# Averaging duplicates in a pandas DataFrame instead of using drop_duplicates to keep first

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-wrangling

Assume that I have a `Pandas DataFrame` of the form:

```
    id      price       dur
1   153     80.0        0.0 
2   153     130.0       0.0 
3   153     95.0        0.0 
4   156     115.0       0.0
5   156     165.0       0.0
6   156     130.0       0.0
7   158     90.0        0.0
8   158     140.0       0.0 
9   158     105.0       0.0
10  158     155.0       0.0
```

And I have a column named `id` and it has `duplicates`. I would like to handle this `duplicates` by keeping a `unique` `id` and then performing an average of the `price` of the `id` instead of using `pd.DataFrame.drop_duplicates()`

Here is my expected output:

```
    id      price       dur
1   153     101.667     0.0 
2   156     136.667     0.0
3   158     122.5       0.0
```

How could I possibly handle this?

Answer (score 1):

For each column is necessary specify aggregate function in [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby('id', as_index=False).agg({'price':'mean', 'dur':'first'})
print (df1)
    id       price  dur
0  153  101.666667  0.0
1  156  136.666667  0.0
2  158  122.500000  0.0
```

But if same values in `dur` for each `id` is possible grouping by both columns:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['id', 'dur'], as_index=False)['price'].mean()
```